# How to change colors in stat_summary()

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to plot two columns of raw data (I have used melt to combine them into one data frame) and then add separate error bars for each.  However, I want to make the raw data for each column one pair of colors and the error bars another set of colors, but I can't seem to get it to work.  The plot I am getting is at the link below. I want to have different color pairs for the raw data and for the error bars. A simple reproducible example is coded below, for illustrative purposes.

```
 dat2.m<-data.frame(obs=c(2,4,6,8,12,16,2,4,6),variable=c("raw","raw","raw","ip","raw","ip","raw","ip","ip"),value=runif(9,0,10))

    c <- ggplot(dat2.m, aes(x=obs, y=value, color=variable,fill=variable,size = 0.02)) +geom_jitter(size=1.25) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","Red"))

   c<- c+stat_summary(fun.data="median_hilow",fun.args=(conf.int=0.95),aes(color=variable), position="dodge",geom="errorbar", size=0.5,lty=1)

    print(c)
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5KHk.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFG7U.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? Or tell us what's going wrong in the plot?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the plot, I'm just not sure how to get the error bars to be a different pair of colors than the raw data.

Comment: simple reproducible example added.

Comment: I have to concur. Coloring the error bars differently from the data points is just likely to cause confusion. It would be fairly easy to make the bars all one color (for example, just set `color = 'black'`), or make the points all one color. But ggplot intentionally makes it very difficult to include multiple color/fill scales, precisely because encoding multiple scales along one dimension is confusing.

Comment: How then can I set it up so that only one category of the data is plotted but the error bars are visible for both categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this would be to use repetitive calls to `geom_point` and `stat_summary`. Use the `data` argument of those functions to feed subsets of your dataset into each call, and set the color attribute outside of `aes()`. It's repetitive and somewhat defeats the compactness of ggplot, but it'd do.

```
c <- ggplot(dat2.m, aes(x = obs, y = value, size = 0.02)) +
    geom_jitter(data = subset(dat2.m, variable == 'raw'), color = 'blue', size=1.25) + 
    geom_jitter(data = subset(dat2.m, variable == 'ip'), color = 'red', size=1.25) +
    stat_summary(data = subset(dat2.m, variable == 'raw'), fun.data="median_hilow", fun.args=(conf.int=0.95), color = 'pink', position="dodge",geom="errorbar", size=0.5,lty=1) +
    stat_summary(data = subset(dat2.m, variable == 'ip'), fun.data="median_hilow", fun.args=(conf.int=0.95), color = 'green', position="dodge",geom="errorbar", size=0.5,lty=1)

print(c)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the record: I think that this is a really, really bad idea. Unless you have a use case where this is crucial, I think you should re-examine your plan.

However, you can get around it by adding a new set of variables, padded with a space at the end. You will want/need to play around with the legends, but this should work (though it is definitely ugly):

```
dat2.m<-    data.frame(obs=c(2,4,6,8,12,16,2,4,6),variable=c("raw","raw","raw","ip","raw","ip","raw","ip","ip"),value=runif(9,0,10))


c <- ggplot(dat2.m, aes(x=obs, y=value, color=variable,fill=variable,size = 0.02)) +geom_jitter(size=1.25) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","Red","green","purple"))

c<- c+stat_summary(fun.data="median_hilow",fun.args=(conf.int=0.95),aes(color=paste(variable," ")), position="dodge",geom="errorbar", size=0.5,lty=1)

print(c)
```